# IIS 7 Log Request Body

Tags: logging, iis-7, request

I need to log the request post payload for requests made to IIS.  Is this possible to configure the logging of request post payloads with the existing logging and advanced logging modules within IIS 7.5 or can anybody direct me to any custom modules that will allow me to log the post payload.

Answer (score 19):

It can actually be done, according to https://serverfault.com/a/90965

> The IIS logs only record querystring and header information without
>   any POST data.
>
> If you're using IIS7, you can enabled Failed Request Tracing for
>   status code 200. That will record all of the data and you can select
>   which type of data to include.

Comment: You don't see the request body this way anyway... Only header and some diagnostic info.

Comment: @Azimuth I haven't verified this, but apparently these fields contain the http body of request and response, respectively: `GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY` and `GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER`

Comment: @Azimuth is incorrect. I setup Failed Request Tracing and got back the entire POST body. Helped me figure out exactly what was being submitted to my API: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/benjaminperkins/archive/2012/01/02/enable-and-activate-failed-request-tracing-rules.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Looks like you only see the request body if there actually was a request body.   GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY is showing it for me (located just under GENERAL_REQUEST_HEADERS, which will presumably always be there).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to create a text file for my requests that contained the entire request (headers and response), I only used it to log specific post requests:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uniqueid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string logfile = String.Format("C:\\path\\to\\folder\\requests\\{0}.txt", uniqueid);
    Request.SaveAs(logfile, true);
}
```

Hopefully this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is code of custom HTTP module we use to log HTTP POST request data.

```
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace MySolution.HttpModules
{
    public class HttpPOSTLogger : IHttpModule
    {

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
        }

        private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null && sender is HttpApplication)
            {
                var request = (sender as HttpApplication).Request;
                var response = (sender as HttpApplication).Response;

                if (request != null && response != null && request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() == "POST")
                {
                    var body = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(request.Form.ToString());
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(body))
                        response.AppendToLog(body);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Do not forget to register it in web.config of you application.

Use system.WebServer section for IIS Integrated Model

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="HttpPOSTLogger" type="MySolution.HttpModules.HttpPOSTLogger, MySolution.HttpModules" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Use system.web section for IIS Classic Model

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="HttpPOSTLogger" type="MySolution.HttpModules.HttpPOSTLogger, MySolution.HttpModules"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

IIS log Before applying module:

```
::1, -, 10/31/2017, 10:53:20, W3SVC1, machine-name, ::1, 5, 681, 662, 200, 0, POST, /MySolution/MyService.svc/MyMethod, -,
```

IIS log After applying module:

```
::1, -, 10/31/2017, 10:53:20, W3SVC1, machine-name, ::1, 5, 681, 662, 200, 0, POST, /MySolution/MyService.svc/MyMethod, {"model":{"Platform":"Mobile","EntityID":"420003"}},
```

Full article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1213108/HttpModule-for-logging-HTTP-POST-data-in-IIS-Log