# file in use message when trying to write out Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, response

I am using the code from this post [IIS 7 Log Request Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523059/iis-7-log-request-body) so that I can see what is happening when people attempt to access my site.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var uniqueid = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  var logfile = String.Format("C:\\logs\\{0}.txt", uniqueid);
  Request.SaveAs(logfile, true);
}
```

When it runs though, I am getting this message:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\logs\635256490792288683.txt' because it is being used by another process.
```

Every once in a while, people are having the of no response from the site and I desperately need to find out what is happening.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of `DateTime.Now` is not good enough for what you are trying to do. For a quick fix, you could use `new Guid().ToString();` but dont do this in production, it is going to really hurt your site performance.

Comment: it'll have to go into production for a short time, at least until I find out what the issue is. Thanks for the help!